# AngularJS 1.x NgTagsInput show message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

I have this code using AngularJS and NGTagsInput.
I'm using Filter in AutoComplete, and you can add new itens pressing 'Enter', but i wanted show this message to user. If there is not a result in auto complete, show message: "No results found. Press Enter to Add"
I tried put a Else inside Filter. but does not work because he checks every single letter.

```
      $scope.loadCountries = function($query) {
    return $http.get('countries.json', { cache: true}).then(function(response) {
      var countries = response.data;
      return countries.filter(function(country) {
        return country.name.toLowerCase().indexOf($query.toLowerCase()) != -1;
      });
    });
  };
});
```

Here is a Plnkr: [PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/5JHEvFZSYNrlymyHmak8?p=preview)

Thanks for now ! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check if there are a returned item matched, in other way just check if the array filtered with that query has an item. If there are no matched item this mean no data :D

```
$scope.loadCountries = function($query) {
    return $http.get('countries.json', { cache: true}).then(function(response) {
      var countries = response.data;
      var filtered = countries.filter(function(country) {
        return country.name.toLowerCase().indexOf($query.toLowerCase()) != -1;
      });
      $scope.nodata = filtered.length === 0;
      return filtered;
    });
  };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/fo1lExzjz0eJxloaljd0?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm! :D